# WPF Link ListView Selected Item with TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to link the notes column on a selected item in a ListView with a TextBox. The idea is when a user clicks an item in the listview they can change the notes about that item. I can then use the notes saved against this item later when saving. The notes header is hidden.

As you can see in the image below I have selected the item in the list and all the selected values come through to the textbox.

1. I only want the AttachmentNotes to come through
2. I want to be able to change those notes and it will then update the binding for the selected item.

[image]

Below is my WPF Code:

```
                <ListView x:Name="LstAttachments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="137" Margin="10,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="641">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Attachment Name" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AttachmentName}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AttachmentPath}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Attachment Type" Width="237" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AttachmentType}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Notes" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AttachmentNotes}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <TextBox x:Name="TxtAttachmentNotes" Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=LstAttachments}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133" Margin="10,235,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="641" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" MaxLength="25000"/>
```

Items are added to the ListView like so:

```
 //Display the File Name and Type in the ListBox
 LstAttachments.Items.Add(new { AttachmentName = RibbonTest.attfilename, AttachmentPath = RibbonTest.attfilename, AttachmentType = RibbonTest.attfiletype, AttachmentNotes = "Test Notes Blah Blah" });
```

All help is much appreciated. :)

Thanks

Comment: As you can see in the sample code I have tried Binding the ListView Selected value with the textbox and that brings back all the values. I know I can then set it to TwoWay to save the information. However I only want to be able to edit the AttachmentNotes Value

Answer (score 1):

I could have misunderstood your problem, but it seems as though the solution is very simple. You have said that you use `SelectedValue` to get the appropriate selected item from the `GridView` but you only want to use one property from this item. Surely, you can just reference your required property by using its name like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtAttachmentNotes" Text="{Binding SelectedValue.AttachmentNotes, 
    ElementName=LstAttachments}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="133"
    Margin="10,235,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="641" 
    SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" MaxLength="25000"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do :) However that does not bring back any data, I dont think you can do it this way with Binding.

Comment: *I don't think you can do it this way with Binding.* You certainly can, although I'm not sure why the result is empty for you... try using the `ListView.SelectedItem` property instead of the `SelectedValue` property because that is really for use in conjunction with the `SelectedValuePath` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your data source on whatever even it appropriate. So maybe on change of the text in the textbox? e.g. on texchange update AttachmentNotes

Comment: I have considered this but I do not use a datasource. Each item in the listview is added individually using variables. I have added an example of how I add data to the ListView at the bottom of my question.

Comment: It sounds like you are not helping yourself. How do you expect to be able to update where the information came from if you do not store it?